# Angular: Uncaught ReferenceError: $cordovaSQLite is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Trying to follow an example for using SQL lite, but hitting a stump.

Example says, include ngCordova in app.js as such:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])
```

That part works.

Then create the DB + table in .run directive:

```
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("space.db");
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS locations (id integer primary key, latitude text, longitude text, altitude text, speed text, date text, time text)");
```

That part works as well...

Then, in services.js i want to add a record when i get the GPS location.

I do that using this code in services.js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Geolocation', function() {

  var callBackFunction ;
  var latitude, longitude, altitude ;

  function getPosition(){
      return new Array(latitude, longitude, altitude, speed, GPSEnabled);
  }

    function showPosition(position) {

      latitude = position.coords.latitude ;
      longitude = position.coords.longitude ;
      altitude = position.coords.altitude ;
        speed = position.coords.speed ;


      var query = "INSERT INTO locations (latitude, longitude, altitude, speed) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [latitude, longitude, altitude, speed, date, time]).then(function(res) {
          console.log("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
      }, function (err) {
          console.error(err);
      });

      callBackFunction(); 
    }

     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError, options);
```

}

However, I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $cordovaSQLite is not defined

How does services.js inherit $cordovaSQLite that's defined in app.js?

Comment: You need to inject it into your `factory` function ~ `.factory('Geolocation', function($cordovaSQLite) { ... })`. I assume that's what you've done in your `run` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject the `$cordovaSQLite` service into your `factory` like this:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Geolocation', ['$cordovaSQLite', function($cordovaSQLite) {
    //do something with $cordovaSQLite
}]);
```

Here is a little more on the syntax I used:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation

**edit**: 
Your module `starter.services` might also be missing the cordova module `ngCordova`:
`angular.module('starter.services', ['ngCordova'])`

Comment: I have the same issue, I check twice ngCordova is added to both services and app.js but Still there is an error